# Resolve multiple dependencies of angular-ui modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, promise, angular-ui-bootstrap

Using angular-ui modal directive I can create a modal and resolve a dependency.

```
$modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'my/path/template.html',
    controller: myController,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    backdrop: 'static',
    resolve: {
        form: _modelFormResolver,
        lists: ['form', function(form) {
            console.log(form);
        }]
    }
});
```

The dependency `form` gets resolved correctly. However, `lists` is depending on `form` to be resolved. This results in an error.

> Unknown provider: formProvider

Is it possible to resolve a parameter with other resolved parameters or do I have to chain them somehow?